# Celsius to Fahrenheit Converter with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to code a Celsius to Fahrenheit (and viceversa) Converter using React Hooks.
But the two way data binding don't work and I don't understand why.
Can somebody help?
Thanks!

Here's my code

```
function GradConverter(){

const [Cgrad, toC] = React.useState(null)
  const [Fgrad, toF] = React.useState(null)

  return(
    <div id="container">
      <div id="box1">
        <h1>Celsius</h1>
        <input
            type = "number"
            value = { Cgrad }
            onChange = {(event) => toF((event.target.value * 9 / 5) + 32).toFixed(2) } >
          </input>
      </div>
      <div id="box2">
          <h1>Fahrenheit</h1>
          <input
            type = "number" 
            value = { Fgrad } 
            onChange = {(event) => toC((event.target.value - 32) * 5 / 9).toFixed(2) } >
          </input>
          </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a single state for both measuring systems, and always update both values when something changes:

```js
function GradConverter(){
  const [temp, updateTemp] = React.useState({ f: 0, c: 0 })

  const updateC = ev => updateTemp({
    c: ev.target.value,
    f: (+ev.target.value * 9 / 5 + 32).toFixed(2)
  })
  
  const updateF = ev => updateTemp({
    c: ((+ev.target.value - 32) * 5 / 9).toFixed(2),
    f: ev.target.value
  })

  return(
    <div id="container">
      <div id="box1">
        <h1>Celsius</h1>
        <input
            type = "number"
            value = {temp.c}
            onChange = {updateC} >
          </input>
      </div>
      <div id="box2">
          <h1>Fahrenheit</h1>
          <input
            type = "number" 
            value = {temp.f} 
            onChange = {updateF}>
          </input>
          </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <GradConverter />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```